# Adonis.js 3.2 watch file changes on views

Tags: npm, watch, nunjucks, adonis.js

How to watch view file changes on adonis.js? Is this possible? or Adonis can only watch js files only? If I change on view files which in (nunjucks) I restart the server so that the changes will be reflected. Please help me I'm just started using adonis.js.

Im using `adonis 3.2` `nunjuck` as view template.

Answer (score 1):

The **watch file** is not a function of **adonis**, is a **nodemon** feature,
you can edit your `packages.json` file
and edit the `serve:dev` property to:

```
"serve:dev": "nodemon -e njk --watch app --watch bootstrap --watch config --watch resources --watch .env -x node server.js",
```

- With the `-e` flag you can pass the extenstion file to listen
- With the `--watch resources` **nodemon** can listen changes